# angular-chart.js not loaded

Tags: html, angularjs, bower, angular-chart

I tried to use angular-chart. I've put Chart.min.js before angular-chart.min.js. Also I've checked those file at my root project. This is the dependency:

```
<script src="/bower_components/chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/angular-chart.js/dist/angular-chart.min.js"></script>
```

But it produces an error:

> (index):72 GET
>   http://localhost:5000/bower_components/chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js 404
>   (Not Found) (index):74 GET
>   http://localhost:5000/bower_components/angular-chart.js/dist/angular-chart.min.js
>   404 (Not Found)

Comment: am sure your urls are wrong

Comment: @Sajeetharan sorry but i've checked again, my urls are right

Comment: are you running the app using xammp?, try accessing the url from the browser

Comment: @Sajeetharan no. im running the app using firebase

Comment: @Sajeetharan i can not access it using the browser. But im sure the urls are right. this is my project root directory https://postimg.org/image/xvofkza8p/